# Merge the [daterange] and [date-range] tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I'm not sure which needs to be merged into which, but I would like to request that the [date-range](/questions/tagged/date-range) and [daterange](/questions/tagged/daterange) tags be merged.

Personally, I'm a fan of hyphens, so I'd like to see [date-range](/questions/tagged/date-range) stick around, but whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `DateRange` is a C#/.NET class. That is why [daterange](/questions/tagged/daterange) is used in [How to know if a DateTime is between a DateRange in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781611/how-to-know-if-a-datetime-is-between-a-daterange-in-c-sharp). I would rather not use [date-range](/questions/tagged/date-range) for questions about the class.

Comment: Hrm, you have a valid point, but having two very similar tag names is just confusing to me.  Neither tag has a wiki saying how to use it, and you've got [Access questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628147/date-range-handling-logic-in-access) and [Oracle questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482168/oracle-sql-show-all-date-time-ranges-if-another-timestamp-does-not-fall-in-betwe) using the `daterange` tag as well.  Does every single .NET class need a tag?

Comment: If the tag doesn't have a tag wiki, then it is better to provide it. I cannot say if every .NET class needs a tag, but if users are using the tag for the class, and it is not just a single user, then the tag it is probably useful.